# GCP multi-region bucket egress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cdn, google-cloud-cdn

If i have a multi-region bucket and if data is read from VM instances, does it count as egress?

Example-  VM instance located in us-west-1 & bucket is configured with US as multi-region.

Second scenario is egress from US multi-region bucket to Google Cloud CDN to serve content in US. I understand that reads from Cloud CDN will count as egress but what about egress from US multi-region bucket to Cloud CDN when there are no cache hits?

Thanks.

Comment: Per the documentation[1]:
Reading data in a Cloud Storage bucket located in a multi-region from a Google Cloud service located in a region on the same continent will no longer be free; instead, such moves will be priced the same as general data moves between different locations on the same continent.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-announce#network

Comment: For Cloud CDN pricing structure, kindly refer to this link: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing#pricing_overview

Answer (score 0):

When you are in multi-region it means your data are replicated over 3 regions on the same continent.

If you have a VM in one of the 3 regions, you have a chance not to pay the egress if the data are served from the current region. But it's not guaranteed and you can't rely on that.

That's why, when you perform Machine Learning training on GCP in a specific region, Google Cloud recommend to use a regional Bucket and not a multi-region: for performance and cost optimization.

---

About the CDN, you will add additional cost. Firstly, you need a load balancer ($15 per month) and then your CDN. And you will minimize the latency (if you use many time the same file) but won't solve the egress cost.

A final word: Cloud Storage act as CDN to serve files, but it's a similar feature it's not a real CDN.